# Is WhatsApp web able to read end to end encrypted messages?

Tags: encryption, whatsapp

Is WhatsApp web able to read end to end encrypted messages between two people who have got their codes scanned?

Answer (score -1):

1) Would say "NO" if they really implemented full end to end encryption..

2) Man in the middle attack scenario still exists

3) I really doubt the end to end encryption for images and videos or files,,. Considering below cases
  a) sending group messages
  b) getting content after a while even if the sender deleted the original files..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and is incorrect anyway. First thing that comes up on google is this [whitepaper](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf) that explains how images and other files are encrypted.